# Changing Size of Vertex Circle

Tags: tikz-graphs

How to change the size of Balls(Vertices)?

```
\documentclass[legalpaper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[paperheight=31cm,paperwidth=7.75cm,bottom=0.5cm,top=0.5cm,left=0cm,right=0cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[upright]{fourier}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\SetVertexNormal[Shape      = circle,
                 FillColor  = black,
                 LineWidth  = 2pt,
                                   ]
\SetUpEdge[lw         = 3pt,
           color      = black,
           labelcolor = white,
          ]


\begin{center}



\begin{tikzpicture}
   \Vertex[x=0 ,y=0]{1}
   \Vertex[x=5 ,y=0]{2}
   \Vertex[x=10,y=0]{3}
   \Vertex[x=15 ,y=0]{4}
   \Vertex[x=17.5 ,y=0]{5}
   \Vertex[x=20 ,y=0]{6}
   \Vertex[x=25 ,y=0]{7}
   \Vertex[x=30 ,y=0]{8}
   \Vertex[x=7.5 ,y=3]{9}
   \Vertex[x=7.5 ,y=-3]{10}
   \Vertex[x=12.5 ,y=-1]{12}
   \Vertex[x=12.5 ,y=-3]{13}
   \Vertex[x=12.5 ,y=1]{14}
   \Vertex[x=12.5 ,y=3]{15}
   \Vertex[x=17.5 ,y=-1]{16}
   \Vertex[x=17.5 ,y=1]{17}
   \Vertex[x=22.5 ,y=1]{18}
   \Vertex[x=22.5 ,y=-1]{19}
   \Edge(1)(2)
   \Edge(2)(9)
   \Edge(2)(10)
   \Edge(10)(3)
   \Edge(3)(9)
   \Edge(3)(14)
   \Edge(3)(15)
   \Edge(3)(12)
   \Edge(3)(13)
   \Edge(4)(13)
   \Edge(4)(14)
   \Edge(4)(12)
   \Edge(15)(4)
   \Edge(4)(17)
   \Edge(4)(16)
   \Edge(4)(5)
   \Edge(5)(6)
   \Edge(6)(17)
   \Edge(16)(6) 
   \Edge(6)(18)
   \Edge(18)(7)
   \Edge(6)(19)
   \Edge(19)(7)
   \Edge(7)(8)  

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried: `\SetVertexNormal[Shape = circle, FillColor = black, LineWidth = 10pt, ]`

Comment: @Wamseln, this will increase only the line width not the radius of the circle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the option `MinSize = 40pt` for example.

[image]

```
\SetVertexNormal[Shape      = circle,
                 FillColor  = black,
                 LineWidth  = 2pt,
                 MinSize    = 40pt,
                                   ]
```

For more details, see the [documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tkz-graph).